# JPA increase @version column count based on another column

Tags: java, jpa

Am new to JPA, Please some one help on the below

My Entity UserTransaction  is below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_transaction")
public class UserTransaction{

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "current_balance")
    private BigDecimal currentBalance;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    private User user;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN default '1'")
    protected Boolean active = true;
}
```

Here am inserting new record with active=1 while user balance getting updated and will change the existing record to active=0. If i want to update my balance i will take active=1 record of my user and calculate my current balance, then update that record active=0 and create new one with active=1.

In this case when multiple threads are trying to change the balance, results creating multiple active=1 records. I was searching solution for this. I got suggestion to add @Version column in my entity. I have added it.

@Version column value increased if i update the existing column, but getting error while inserting another column with version for another user.

Is it possible to increase version column count based on user? Else give me suggestion to handle my user balance during concurrency.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The `@Version` property is specific to a single row. This allows your JPA provider to detect updates to the *same row*. It sounds like you want to serialize inserts and updates into the table?

Comment: `In this case when multiple threads are trying to change the balance` - why would you change the same balance instance? If I understood you correctly, you take balance from old instance, and recalculate it for new instance, which you then persist to database? Just make a copy of `currentBalance` and do the calculations on it. BTW, if this is the case, `@Version` is not needed at all.

Comment: @Predrag, you understood my point, If `@Version` is not required , please suggest me solution to handle this case. Am having balance in my old instance, two new requests trying to recalculate the new balance at the same time . Finally two request created two new instance for balance. But i want this to be synchronized.

Comment: Here is some basic pseudo code: 1. `UserTransaction oldUT = getUT(id); oldUT.setActive(false);` 2. `UserTransaction newUT = new UserTransaction(oldUT /*or empty*/);` 3. `newUT.setCurrentBalance(recalculateBalance(oldUT.getCurrentBalance()));` 4. `update(oldUT); save(newUT);`. It could still be that I misunderstood the problem, though.